# Mapping Disks to Initiators using Powershell

Tags: powershell

I am using Windows Server 2016 with Powershell 7.0.2. I want to get the target IDs (WWNs or iSCSI Addresses) for my connected storages shown as disks. I get the disks on my Windows Server using get-disk

```
$Disks=get-disk
```

I can get if these are attached through iscsi or FC from BusType attribute. Then I can get the local port info

```
$Ports=Get-initiatorPort
```

I can get the Address (FC or ISCSI) from NodeAddress. At this point I am stuck.

1. How do I map which disk is using which NodeAddress on initiator
2. How do I get the target system ID (icsci iqn or FC WWN)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass your disk object right to `Get-IscsiSession` which can give you some of the details you're looking for.

An example:

```
$DiskList = Get-Disk | Where-Object { $_.BusType -eq 'iSCSI' ]
foreach ($Disk in $DiskList) {
    $SessionList = $Disk | Get-IscsiSession
    foreach ($Session in $SessionList) {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            Name = $Disk.FriendlyName
            InitiatorNode = $Session.InitiatorNodeAddress
            TargetNode = $Session.TargetNodeAddress
        }
    }
}
```

The only server I have to test on has PowerShell 4 with iSCSI multipath connections. You may not need the SessionList loop if you don't use MPIO.

Comment: Altough I am not clear on which property of Disk object is matched in  ISCSISession, it works for iSCSI. The bigger part on FC still remains. There are some tidbits in https://www.purepowershellguy.com/?p=54 but it does not work anymore

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't be of much help there, as I have nothing to test on.